# Post created with Graph API Explorer with success but unavailable for anyone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have published Posts in a Page I created with the Facebook Graph API and it returns a successful response containing the newly created post_id, its permalink, etc.

However, only my user (creator of the Page) can see the Post published this way. It is unavailable to all other people - including other Page administrators.

Here is the request with its "successful" response: https://i.ibb.co/gPdkTDV/Capture-d-e-cran-2020-03-30-a-15-38-28.png

Permalink URL from the screenshot: https://www.facebook.com/113704106942055/posts/114980426814423/ (unavailable for everyone but my user)

Post visible from my account: https://i.ibb.co/j8n4d7T/Capture-d-e-cran-2020-03-30-a-15-50-12.png

Any idea why this content is unavailable ?

Notes:

- This request is the same as showed in documentation for [read-after-write](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#read-after-write)
- It's also the same as showed in [`/feed` endpoint, Publish section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page/feed#publish)
- I get my Page Access Token using [Get Access Tokens of Pages You Manage](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-access-tokens-of-pages-you-manage), without any errors
- I was using the Python sdk `facebook` and had this error, then tried with the raw Python `requests` module. I was thinking the problem came from a misusage of one of those, but since the result is the same with the official Facebook Graph API Explorer, I don't know where the problem could be from.
- The created post is in public mode.
- Post created with the usual web interface (not via FB Graph API/Requests) are visible from everyone.
- The Page Settings looks right: it's in Published mode, even Visitors can 
  publish posts and photos on the Page.
- There is no App linked to this Page.

Debug informations from Graph API Explorer:

```
==== Query
 curl -i -X POST \
  "https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/feed?message=Coucou%20!&fields=created_time%2Cfrom%2Cid%2Cmessage%2Cpermalink_url&access_token=<access token sanitized>"

==== Access Token Info
 {
   "perms": [
     "manage_pages",
     "pages_show_list",
     "publish_pages",
     "business_management",
     "public_profile"
   ],
   "page_id": 113704106942055,
   "user_id": <hidden>,
   "app_id": 2816738828445148
 }

==== Parameters
- Query Parameters

{
   "message": "Coucou !",
   "fields": "created_time,from,id,message,permalink_url"
 }

- POST Parameters
{}

==== Response
 {
   "created_time": "2020-03-30T13:38:10+0000",
   "from": {
     "name": "Recipe Ideas Generator",
     "id": "113704106942055"
   },
   "id": "113704106942055_114980426814423",
   "message": "Coucou !",
   "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/113704106942055/posts/114980426814423/",
   "__debug__": {}
 }
```

Any hints or leads to a solution would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is your app Live?

Comment: @WizKid I don't use an app, I get my Page Access Token from my User Access Token, following this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-access-tokens-of-pages-you-manage

Comment: You must have an app. That is the only way to get an access token.

Comment: Check the access token info you have shown inside your post, it’s right there - `"app_id": 2816738828445148`

Comment: You need to put your app  in live mode, for content created via it to be visible for everyone. But you will have to submit your app for review of the `manage_pages` permission, otherwise you won’t be able to ask for that in live mode, and without it, you can’t post to your page.